# AB testing using FXM Javascript Beacon

Tags: fxm, goals

We're experiencing an issue regarding the FXM and AB testing (9.2 version). 
At the moment, we're using the FXM javascript beacon to trigger a goal in an external website page. The goal is correctly triggered and properly assign to a contact, but it's not being registered on AB test result. 
Since the [Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/requirements-and-limitations.html) indicates that FXM does not support MV test/AB Testing, is there any other way to do it?